# horizontal scroll on mobile resolution with responsive css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a site for my client which i need to design with cross platform compability. I don't know what i am doing wrong with the css codes. but for the `width` below `1024px` i set the `wrapper` width to `100%`. When i resize my firefox to 768, it was creating a small amount of horizontal scroll (approx 10px). So i set the with of the tablet to 730px so that it wouldn't get any horizontal scroll but even the same problem is causing with mobile resolution.

I have read most of the blogs related to this topic and they are suggesting for `overflow-x:hidden`. This might not be the best solution for this. Please help me out to solve this issue.

site link : [socialelections](http://www.socialelections.com/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for the repliers.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in Firefox, Chrome and Android Chrome.

Comment: I am viewing on Desktop browser Firefox, there's still horizontal scroll in the width 320 PX. However i checked in iphone (potrait and landscape) its fine(strange). But desktop still.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a debug for your site and I came to know that there is a wrapper container width for all device, it should be 240px for mobile rather than 320px.

Please check you site url here for all device...http://mattkersley.com/responsive/

Comment: but i have checked in iphone there's no h-scroll but same width (320px) in the browser there's scroll.